# How to recursively update only git submodules that are set up to track a branch?

Tags: git, git-submodules

Let's say my `.gitmodules` defines many submodules. Some submodules track branches while others don't.

In my desired workflow, I'd run a single command that updates only the submodules which track a branch. All other submodules would remain fixed to their commit, rather than updating to the latest remote HEAD.

Running the typical recursive submodule update command would update all submodules, which is not desired:

`git submodule update --recursive --remote --checkout`

I've tried specifying a tag in the branch field of a submodule in `.gitmodules`, but the tag is not recognized as an appropriate reference. (a SHA also doesn't work, as expected):

`$ git submodule update --recursive --remote --checkout`

`fatal: Unable to find refs/remotes/origin/tags/<tag> revision in submodule path <path>`

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you would need a script, since a one-liner is a bit too complex to come up with.

Something like, using [`git submodule foreach`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule/#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-foreach--recursiveltcommandgt):

```bash
#!/bin/bash

git submodule foreach '
  branch=$(git config -f $toplevel/.gitmodules submodule.$name.branch);
  if [ -n "$branch" ]; then
    echo "Updating submodule: $name";
    git switch $branch;
    git pull origin $branch;
  else
    echo "Skipping submodule: $name (no branch specified)";
  fi
'
```